# How to make video view go off screen?

Tags: android, resize, screen, android-videoview

How would I make a Video View start at the top of the screen and then continue down and eventually go off the bottom of the screen?  Everything I try just resizes the video to fit on the screen no matter what. So how would I change this to get the video to not fit on the screen all the way. Thanks for the help and especially for examples.

like this high quality diagram shows:

```
    ________
    |      |
    |   V  |
    |   I  |
    |   D  |
    |___E__|
        O
```

The video going off the screen. but you really couldn't see the O because it would be off the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set VideoView size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10038283/how-can-i-set-videoview-size)